# Programmatically creating a list of videos

Tags: android, vimeo

I'm trying to create a list of videos that a user may view. This needs to be dynamic because the list is going to update based on new entries being added to the database I'm drawing the videos from.

For my project, I access a list of videos from vimeo through its simple API. The current approach I'm using to display all the info is through a webview object that gets its info from a StringBuilder object, htmlString.

My XML for the view is the following:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/videoMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The snippet of code that I use to build my list dynamically is the following. It returns to a function "onPostExecute(String result)" which displays the webview with the html created from the for loop.

```
    for (VideoDataParser.Entry video : videos)
    {
        htmlString.append("<p>");
        htmlString.append("<a href=\"" + video.url + "\">");
        htmlString.append("<img align=\"left\" src=\"" + video.thumbnail_url + "\">");
        htmlString.append(video.title + "<br>");
        htmlString.append(video.description);
        htmlString.append("</p>");

    }
    return htmlString.toString();
```

The main problem I have now is that the images aren't loading. I suppose that's because it requires another HTTP request to get the image. Is there another way to fix that?

Also, I feel like this method of creating a menu might not be the best. When the user clicks the link, the flow of control goes outside of my activities and goes to a web browser where it will play the video. I want the activity to go to my own video player instead of using the internet upon clicking one of my options. There is most likely a better way of doing this, but I'm unsure.

Any input would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a WebView to create your playlist, then I would recommend using JavaScript interfaces inside the WebView so you can send information between your activity and the WebView, so when the user clicks a thumbnail you can send the activity the "id" of the thumbnail the user clicked.

Tips:

**To add an interface you do it this way**

```
WebView web = new WebView();
web.addJavascriptInterface(new classWhereTheMethodsAre(), "nameOfTheInterface");
```

**To call the method from inside HTML**

```
nameOfTheInterface.nameOfTheMethod(Parameters);
```

I hope this tips can help you, if you have another question please post it here, and I will try to solve it or maybe give you an snippet.

**UPDATE:**

If your images come from the "internet" (HTTP or something like that), then you can just put the URL in the HTML code like you would normally do so, or you can download them to the SD CARD (with your asynctask class) and then have a listener to advise you when the image is completely downloaded so you can ["lazy load"](http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2010/html-lazy-load/) the part of the code where you "insert" the image to the HTML page. The lazy load can be achieved with the code provided in the link and to call it you can do a `YourWebView.loadUrl("javascript:functionThatCallsTheLazyLoad(Parameters)")`

I hope this update can help you with your problem.

Comment: Thanks! That's helpful! I've been looking into this approach fairly extensively after you posted this and it seems like it could really work!

One other question. I am still trying to figure out a way to get the image thumbnails to show in the list. Is there a way to load up those images?

Comment: Of course there are ways to do that, but it depends of from where your images come. If you are loading those images from the SD card or from the assets, you will have to use the [loaddatawithbaseurl](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) and send your html like a String and your baseurl would be depending from where your images come from. If your images are from URLS then you can just use the loaddata method and point to the images from the html. i hope this solves your question, if not please replay.

Comment: Also if this solves your problem, please mark the answer as accepted so if anyone comes and see it, they will know that helped you.

Comment: Thank you. I marked this as accepted because the original problem is solved. I will reply if I run into any more snags.

Comment: Ok, so I'm having trouble trying to figure out a way to get the images to show. The images come from the internet. I'd imagine that it would require a separate AsyncTask class to to that stuff. I suppose I can create a nested AsyncTask class within the current class (The java code in the sample code above is within my AsyncTask class already). Even if I got the images to download, how would I display them in the html?

Comment: Thank you! I found out the reason that the images weren't loading. It was a simple parsing error on my part resulting in the thumbnail_url item to return null rather than a legitimate url.

Thank you for all your help!